# MySQL server connection is hitting limit of magical number 4832

Tags: mysql, max-connections

Have been monitoring mysql server for year, I notice the mysql database **max_used_connections** cannot get pass **4832**. Once hitting 4832, MySQL begins to show slowness, while the loads/cpu usage/memory are under moderate usage. The **max_connections** is set to 6000 (*SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "max_connections"*). Running **Ubuntu 20.04, Mysql5.7.33**
Below are configuration I modified:

mysql.conf

```
max_connections = 6000 # have tried other values like 10000
open_files_limit = 1048576
```

Modifying /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service

```
LimitNOFILE=infinity 
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
```

/etc/security/limits.conf

```
*    soft nofile 1048576
*    hard nofile 1048576
*    soft nproc  1084576
mysql   soft    nproc   1084576
mysql   hard    nproc   1084576
mysql   soft    nofile   1084576
mysql   hard    nofile   1084576
```

Ulimit

```
ulimit -n; // 1048576
ulimit -u; // 257436
```

Previously the server is 12 core 48GB memory, hitting 4832. I upgraded to 16 core 64GB memory, max_used_connections still hitting 4832 max. It is always hitting 4832 and no further. Any ideas?

Comment: `mysql.conf` is this the exact filename, `my{sql}.cnf` is usually the extension used. Can you share a `show global status` when the limit is reached. Does the slowdown occur regardless of what the connections are doing (e.g. `select sleep(600)`)?

Comment: I will share again if it happens. The slowdown only occurs when 4832 limit is hit.
The variable query from mysql, max_connections is already 6000 or any value I modified.

Comment: the max connection limit iws not only a mysql problem, there are also operation system values that influence it.

Comment: @nbk but where else ?

Comment: that is something for ubuntu specialists, so try your luck there, but i believe there are a lot of qustions arpund that

Comment: Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the system started swapping.  *That* is terrible for performance.

Almost *no* MySQL system really needs more than 1000 connections.  Before addressing that, what to you get from this (when it hits 4823)?

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Threads_running';
```

I need some more info...  RAM size, values of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, `max_connections`.  Is this a web app?  Or are the clients something else?

A typical problem comes from the clients (eg, web server children) being unnecessarily numerous.  I suggest this is the first thing to tackle.  Lower the "max_children" (or whatever).

If `Threads_running` is more than 20, then you probably have some slow queries that need optimizing.  Set `long_query_time = 1` and turn on the slowlog.  After some time, use `pt-query-digest` to analyze the slowlog for naughty queries.

More:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis

Comment: Threads_running is 10. I am still identifying what could cause the problem (eg malicious scraping). However, no matter how is my settings, it always hit 4832 only. Is this the limit of MySQL ?
max_connections = 6000
innodb_buffer_pool_size=24G

Comment: @neobie - Nothing magical about 4832.  Set `max_connections` lower than that; see what happens.